# Volley Post request returns no response inside onResponse

Tags: java, android, json, post, android-volley

So I wanna print the result of the response and then generates data for the models using gson, but the response never gets return yet onResponse is called.!

if you notice Logcat, the log.i inside onResponse isn't showing..!? but inside the onSuccess of the Activity that uses this request, it shows logs normally, but if the log contains the response object it does not show which very weird and doesn't make any sense..!?

Logcat

```
I/getUrl:: http://1925.232.55/login.php
I/getParams:: {username =samy, password=123456}
D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornetcontext+,hn 20(0x6),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 1024, proc=com...
D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfo_proxy get netid:0
D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfo_proxy-, success
I/onSuccess:: check /* this log inside the Activity which uses this request */
```

> I tried test the request using PostMan with the same url and params
>   and it returns json response normally..?

Postman response

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "user_id": "10",
    "user_name": "samy",
    "full_name": "samy samy",
    "picture": "st_pictures/IMG_085207.jpg",
    "level": "1",
    "school": "NY School",
    "city": "NY",
    "class": "6",
    "age": "22",
    "teacher": "2",
    "token": "f808e758sdfsdfsf162dbdfcf88e3dc8a96"
}
```

The request code

```
 final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

      final StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, getLoginURL(), new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
          Log.i("onResponse: ", response + "");
      requestResult.onSuccess(response);


      }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
      requestResult.onFail(error);

           VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
          error.printStackTrace();
        }
      })
      {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
          Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
          params.put("username ", un);
          params.put("password", pass);
          Log.i( "getParams: ", params.toString());
          return params;
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
          Log.i( "getUrl: ",getUrl());
          return super.getBody();

        }
      }
      ;

      queue.add(sr);
```

**UPDATE #1**

URL `http://clients.intertech.ps/raz/std.php`

```
 E/Volley: [1] 2.onErrorResponse: Error: 
 W/System.err: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
 W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest.parseNetworkResponse(JsonObjectRequest.java:73)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:123)
 W/System.err: Caused by: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
 W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:449)
 W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
 W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:156)
 W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest.parseNetworkResponse(JsonObjectRequest.java:68)
 W/System.err:  ... 1 more
```

Comment: first log is ` http://1925.232.55/login.php` i think your url is wrong

Comment: @OussemaAroua this one is a dummy one, do you want me to replace it with the real one?

Comment: no need to i'm just cheking if it's real or not

Comment: would it help you if I add the response that comes from Postman..!

Comment: yes please if you can

Comment: @OussemaAroua done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This question was asked a long time ago but I had the same problem, after hours I got it to work with Volley**

Used `StringRequest` instead of JsonObjectRequest, for any reason i got to much problems with JOR and I used the `getHeaders` function of [@Oussema Aroua](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45326409)

```
final Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("RESPONSE", String.valueOf(response));
        }
    };

final Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            //Handle your errors
        }
    };

StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            responseListener, errorListener) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            //Put your params for post
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); //-> this is the key
            return params;
        }
    };
```

.. and you will get the json response from the server in `onResponse`

Answer (score 0):

it's not a `StringRequest` you need to use `JsonObjectRequest` be cause your response begin with the `{`

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                       requestResult.onSuccess(response);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        requestResult.onFail(error);
                    }
                });
```

try to add under the `getParams`:

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    return params;
}
```

[UPDATE] :

i have no idea why with volley is not working but i changes to `ion` [link](https://github.com/koush/ion) and it works :

```
Ion.with(this)
                .load("http://clients.intertech.ps/raz/std.php")
                .setBodyParameter("username", "layal")
                .setBodyParameter("password", "123456")
                .asJsonObject()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject jsonObject) {
                        Log.e("TAG", "onCompleted: " + jsonObject.toString());
                    }
                });
```

Comment: I change it to a JsonObjectRequest and this error shows: ` E/Volley: [1] 2.onErrorResponse: Error:  org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of `

Comment: the response from the server is empty it returns nothing

Comment: I did, same problem, see UPDATE #1 again, I'll post the real `url`, use it in postman with the prams and see for yourself .!

Comment: it acts like the php file doesn't get the username and password, try to add `if (!isset($_POST["username"]) echo "empty username"`

Comment: I didn't write the web-side logic, it was given to me like this and I don't know who did the web api !

Comment: try to add the getheaders method, i added it to my answer

Comment: same error ..!? what is happening.. !? can please run the request and see if works with you..!? I know it's too much to ask, but I'm drowning here man..! remember to use the updated username

Comment: when the server receive no data the response body is empty that's what happening now

Comment: humm, I tried to send params with both ways using @attakon method and yours and none of them seems to be working, is there a third way?

Comment: check updated answer it works for me and i will try with volley this time

Comment: let me know if it did, because if not, I'll use `Ion` then.

Comment: sorry no luck with volley

Comment: I think I'm gonna abandon Volley for good, Ion seems way simpler! thanx a lot man, I'll try it out and see :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150200/discussion-between-oussema-aroua-and-sam-zar).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a `JsonObjectRequest`, like this :

```
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("username","samy");
params.put("password","123456");

JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, new JSONObject(params),
 new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
           Gson gson = new Gson();
           YourClass yourClass = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), yourClass.class);
       }
   }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
       @Override
       public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //error
       }
   });
```

Comment: it didn't work, it gives me same error as the `@OussemaAroua` answers, see UPDATE #1 for full logcat

Comment: can you double check your json response, probably it's not well formed

Comment: see UPDATE #1 again, I'll post the real `url`, use it in postman with the prams and see for yourself .!

Comment: I'm getting a blank response

Comment: sorry, use this username "layal" instead of samy